# problem compile and installing kaffeine manually

Tags: 14.04, cmake

I am a bit new to compiling packages manually and I have downloaded kaffeine from [here](http://git://anongit.kde.org/kaffeine). And when I type `cmake .`, I get the following error:

```
-- Found Qt-Version 5.2.1 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QT_QT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/yashar/kaffeine/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed

CMake Error at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake:1311 (message):
  Unable to compile a basic Qt application.  Qt has not been found correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:95 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/yashar/kaffeine/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/yashar/kaffeine/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Recently kaffeine 1.2.2-3, in the Ubuntu repositories, has become "flaky". The kaffeine window goes black when you click off focus and it looses window size when changing channels.

This is usually something to do with dependency issues. Making my own version usually fixes at least some of those issues. I have had the same problems compiling some versions of the kaffeine source. Anyway, just retried the github download with the path to Qt4 defined on the cmake - and at last, it compiles.

git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kaffeine

I found the following fixed that error on my system, as it is to do with qt5 and qt4 library defaults changed. You have to specify Qt4 now.

```
cd kaffeine  
mkdir build  
cd build  
cmake .. -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
```

That built and worked, but still found the sound dropped occasionally, so still some issues.